# Preimage of linear map preserves inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume two sets $A$, $B\in R^n$, and define $\bar{A}=\{x\in R^m:Tx\in A\}$, $\bar{B}=\{x\in R^m:Tx\in B\}$, where $T$ is some $(n\times m)$ matrix. Under which conditions does it hold that $A\neq B \Rightarrow \bar{A}\neq\bar{B}$ .

My guess is that $n\leq m$ and full rank is required in order to have a injection when the inverse transformation is applied, however I was not able to show this in a more rigorous way.

Comment: Actually, note that $A$ is not necessary a image of $\bar{A}$. However what I was thinking that clearly $(A\neq B \Rightarrow \bar{A}\neq \bar{B}) \Leftrightarrow (\bar{A}= \bar{B} \Rightarrow A=B)$ thus following by contradiction and assuming that $\bar{A}= \bar{B} \Rightarrow A\neq B$ is clearly true only if the map cannot cover the whole $R^n$ which is however impossible if $T$ has full rank and $n\leq m$. What do you think?

Comment: You're right I misread that definition. I'd still take the contra-positive and search for algebraic expressions of your condition. Your question is a "what is equivalent to this?" kind of question.